# Google Places and ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I've been working on this very simple Google Places search and I cannot get anything but a ZERO_RESULTS. It makes no sense to me at this point as my map is working and displays markers from my database within a separate AJAX function. I've logged my objects and variables and all seem to be just fine.

Why does the success callback go right to my else statement with ZERO_RESULTS?

```
$( "#submit3" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    findPlaces();
    $('#results').text("Triggah3!");
});

function findPlaces() {

    var lat = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
    var lng = document.getElementById("longitude").value;
    var cur_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    // prepare request to Places
    var request = {
        location: cur_location,
        radius: 50000,
        types: 'bank'
    };

    // send request
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, createMarkers);
}

// create markers (from 'findPlaces' function)
function createMarkers(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) { //ZERO_RESULTS

        // if we have found something - clear map (overlays)
        clearOverlays();

        // and create new markers by search result
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    } else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
        alert('Sorry, nothing is found');
    }
}

// create single marker function
function createMarker(obj) {

    // prepare new Marker object
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: obj.geometry.location,
        map: map,
        title: obj.name
    });
    markers.push(mark);

    // prepare info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<img src="' + obj.icon + '" /><font style="color:#000;">' + obj.name + 
        '<br />Rating: ' + obj.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + obj.vicinity + '</font>'
    });

    // add event handler to current marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
        clearInfos();
        infowindow.open(map,mark);
    });
    infos.push(infowindow);
}
```

Comment: Turns out that is must have been an API issue. It mysteriously started working on my first refresh today... The code is correct.

Comment: Might have been that you are over your limit? I think Google Places only allows a certain amount of requests per day.

Comment: Good thinking, but the API key was brand new for Places. The only thing that makes sense is that Google didn't flip my switch for 24 hours....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`types` is expected to be an array.

Use:

```
types: ['bank']
```

Comment: Ah ha! I am using types: (['bank']) probably why it worked! You are awarded the answer kind sir.